# Sound level of a sound given the distance, sound pressure and acoustic impedance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

I was given this physics problem in class:

> Calculate the sound level of a sound at 10 cm away from a PC-fan if
>   the effective sound pressure is 0.04421/2 $\frac{N}{m^2}$ and the acoustic
>   impedance is 442 $\frac{Ns}{m^3}$ ($I_0$ = 10-12 W/m2).

Everything fits nicely in the formula: $N=10log\left(\frac{I}{I_0}\right)$ except the given distance (10 cm). What do I do with it? I know about the inverse proportional law, but here it seems useless.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a unique answer for this. A PC fan is sufficiently large that "10 cm" is close by - close enough that the inverse square law doesn't yet apply (source is not a point source at that distance). Could it be that you are expected to make some assumptions?

Comment: Very probable, but he might have added useless data to the problem to make it seem more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the distance is just telling you "at this distance, we measured the effective sound pressure." It's relevant when you interpret the answer. "When you are close to the fan, it sounds this loud."

That means you don't need to include the distance in your calculation - all you need is the pressure and impedance.

And you already know how to do that.